# Random 404 error problem on a host using Plesk

Tags: laravel, debugging, logging, http-status-code-404, plesk

I am deploying a website designed in Laravel 10 with PHP 8.2. Everything is fine locally until I deploy to the production server.
But not everything goes as planned. The pages are accessed randomly. it is sometimes necessary to refresh before having the corresponding page. Randomly, I have default page or a 404 page with the following message:

DEFAULT Error Page

[image: 1]

404 Error Page

[image: 2]

I need your help.
Thanks in advance.

I looked at the host log and the PHP log, but nothing abnormal (code 200).

Answer (score 1):

This occured to me as well today. It seems it's an [old issue](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/lots-of-404-errors-for-new-wordpress-sites.365881/), but the workaround is simple: restart apache.

Login via ssh, and run: `service apache2 restart` . No more random 404 errors after that.

Comment: This is a hosting that I bought. I don't have access to SSH. How to proceed ?

Comment: Contact your host to restart it for you.

Comment: OK, thank you.
I contacted customer service and the problem was resolved.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you so much! After a few hours of head scratching, this was *the* solution!